# Support PHP 8's attributes for my routes in custom Symfony framework

Tags: symfony, php-8

I've followed the [Symfony Tutorial Series](https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html) to create my own Symfony framework. Currently I have the following code to define my routes and add them to the `UrlMatcher`:

```php
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$routes = include __DIR__.'/../src/app.php';

$context = new Routing\RequestContext();
$matcher = new Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher($routes, $context);
```

Here's my `app.php` file for reference:

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing;

$routes = new Routing\RouteCollection();

$routes->add('leap_year', new Routing\Route('/is_leap_year/{year}', [
    'year' => null,
    '_controller' => 'App\Controller\LeapYearController::index',
]));

return $routes;
```

What's the simplest way this can be modified to support PHP 8's attributes against the `LeapYearController`'s actions for my routes instead of defining them in the `app.php` file?

It's been a while since I last looked at Symfony and a lot has changed in the framework aswell as in PHP itself and so far everything I have found is no longer supported.

Comment: This is a 5.1 [repo](https://github.com/cerad/routing) from a few years ago showing how to use annotations outside of the framework.  I have not bothered to update it to use attributes but I would imagine the steps are similar.

Comment: afaik attributes and annotation are basically alias, so the solution of cerad should still work -- did you already try amending the loader to include the annotation one?

Comment: @Federkun the bit I don't like is how it has a dependency on Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader.

Comment: @nfplee  You should be able to remove the Doctrine dependency.  I'll look at it when I get motivated.  There should be an AttributeReader class someplace in the Symfony namespace.

Comment: @nfplee I also messed around a bit.  The newly introduced (6.2) Psr4DirectoryLoader is what the framework uses so I'd say it is probably the way to go.  Wrapping it in a resolver is a pain but again that is what the framework does.  The framework also has it's own AnnotationClassLoader with a few extra bits (such as handling Controller::__invoke) but your version works fine.  As far as a `nicer` way goes, picking your components and wiring them up sounds nice but the wiring can often get messy.  It's why frameworks are popular.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad, that's largely what I found. I couldn't see the code in the framework which handled this. I looked at the tests and took it from there. If you could provide a link on GitHub that would be great.

Comment: The trick is to look for service definitions in the framework-bundle.  In this case there is a Resources/config/routing.php file which sounded promising.  Then you just sort of browse through the various routing services to see how things are wired together.  `debug:container` also helps as well as actually looking at the generated container and the routing compiler pass.  The Psr4DirectoryLoader is mentioned in the docs so that was really the starting point.  Just a big puzzle to fit the pieces together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the following working:

```php
$loader = new AnnotationDirectoryLoader(
    new FileLocator(),
    new class() extends AnnotationClassLoader {
        protected function configureRoute(Route $route, \ReflectionClass $class, \ReflectionMethod $method, object $annot) {
            $route->setDefault('_controller', $class->getName() . '::' . $method->getName());
        }
    }
);

$routes = $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/../src/App/Controller');
```

Alternatively this works using the `Psr4DirectoryLoader` introduced in [version 6.2](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-2-psr-4-route-loader):

```php
$loader = new DelegatingLoader(
    new LoaderResolver([
        new Psr4DirectoryLoader(
            new FileLocator()
        ),
        new class() extends AnnotationClassLoader {
            protected function configureRoute(Route $route, \ReflectionClass $class, \ReflectionMethod $method, object $annot) {
                $route->setDefault('_controller', $class->getName() . '::' . $method->getName());
            }
        }
    ])
);

$routes = $loader->load(['path' => __DIR__ . '/../src/App/Controller', 'namespace' => 'App\Controller'], 'attribute');
```